# How to develop test-automation using Postman when OAuth 2.0 authorization is required

Tags: asp.net-web-api, automated-tests, asp.net-web-api2, postman, newman

I have an ASP.NET Web API 2 which is using OAuth 2.0 for authorization. And let's imagine I have a simple Web API method, like:

```
GET: http://host/api/profiles/user123   (requires OAuth 2.0 token)
```

So, with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/), it is easy to test this Web API. I get an OAuth token for `user123` from the Web API OAuthAuthorization method and then I use that token in the header of the HTTP request:

```
GET /api/profiles/user123   HTTP/1.1
Host: {host}
Authorization: Bearer {Token}
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

However, if I save my test and run it later (either by Postman itself or by [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro)), the token will be expired at that time and it won't work.

How can I make [Newman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro) to get a new token automatically for `user123` and use it in the HTTP request?

Note: I know how to use Postman's [Authentication helpers](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/helpers) to ask for a new token. But this scenario doesn't fit the test-automation. In test-automation, I want to remove any human interaction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple, get your access token at run time and save it into environment variable. Then use it in your next Get request.

In Get Token request, do this in Tests sections:

```
var body = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set('AccessToken', body.access_token);
```

In your main Get request, you can use the environment variable in `Authorization` header:

```
Authorization: Bearer {{AccessToken}}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi @Pandit81 - Any idea how to order/reorder the saved items in a collection in Postman, so I make sure that the "Get Token" happens before all other items and tests?

Comment: @Tohid Individual requests within a folder can be manually placed in  whatever order you want and they run in that order. For folders, I use numbers presets like 101 Access Token, 102 Get Request etc.

Comment: Here's the answer to ordering question in detail > 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336057/postman-is-it-possible-to-customize-the-sequence-of-test-runs-in-the-collection