# Postman: Is it possible to customize the sequence of test runs in the collection runner

Tags: postman

I have several tests in my postman collection but some of them are dependent on few others from within the collection as the latter set some envt variables that are used by other tests. I want these to run in a sequence. The tests in my collection are distributed across different folders. Is there a possibility to define such a sequence in a test suite like structure?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The execution happens according to how the folders and tests within each is displayed inside Postman.

In a collection, I normally number my folders according to the execution order and then the individual tests can be prefixed with numbers as well, so that you control the execution.
Refer to the attached screenshot.

[image]

Also there's a `postman.setNextRequest('Request-title');` method to customize which request you want to execute next.

Source - http://blog.getpostman.com/2016/03/23/conditional-workflows-in-postman/

Comment: Postman really lacks the feature of defining test cases separately. I'd love to be able to combine my requests in different order to define test cases for different scenarios. At the moment the monitor feature feels more like a dumb executioner of whatever you collection structure is like.

Answer (score 6):

You can drag/drop requests in postman in order that you want to be executed in Collection Runner

Comment: Tried that and to verify if it worked, I shift-reloaded the browser page. It looks like that it always resets and is not on the application level, just somewhere in the DOM.

Comment: thank you so much. I reorder delete methods to another folder so I forced them to run at the end but my grouping that made by category disordered. This is better if we can disable them and define a shortcut to every item. or design a UI for prioritized items without move

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/8433
The above link offers a good suggestion for "Recent Runs". Hope it is going to be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

You could sort now requests by drag and drop them to fit your order